# How I resolve the method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null, when using Navigator?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0 to implement set password functionality in my flutter app. when a user is created by admin, user receives an email. In this email there is a dynamic link. On clicking it the user is redirected to 
1.App store/play store if he/she does not have the App.
2.Opens up set password screen in app if the app is already installed.
firebase_dynamic_links provides two methods :-
1.getInitialLink a future to retrieve the link that opened the app.
2.onLink a callback to listen to links opened while the app is active or in background.

All goes well when app is in killed state and link is pressed but when app is in back ground then navigation is not working.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: new ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colours.appThemeColour,
    ),
    onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
      switch (settings.name) {
        case '/': return new MyCustomRoute(
          builder: (_) => new SplashScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
        case '/setpassword': return new MyCustomRoute(
          builder: (_) => new SetPassword(settings.arguments),
          settings: settings,
        );
     ...


      }
    }
)
);

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
Uri deepLink;


  _handleDeepLink(Uri deepLink) async{
    if (deepLink != null) {
      print("querParam=${deepLink.queryParameters["token"]}");
      if(deepLink.queryParameters["otp"].toString()=="1"){
        if(deepLink.queryParameters["token"]!=null){
          String _status =await _networkUtil.verifyUser(deepLink.queryParameters["token"].toString());
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/setpassword',arguments: _status );


        }else{
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/setpassword',arguments: "unknownError" );
        }
      }
      else{
        if(deepLink.queryParameters["token"]!=null){
          String _status =await _networkUtil.verifyUser(deepLink.queryParameters["token"].toString());
          SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/resetpassword');
          });
        }else{
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/resetpassword');
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
  initDynamicLinks() async {

    final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;

    if (deepLink != null) {
      _handleDeepLink(deepLink);

    }

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
          final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
          _handleDeepLink(deepLink);

        },
        onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
          print('onLinkError');
          print(e.message);
        }
    );
  }
@override
initState(){
initDynamicLinks().then((){
...

});
}
```

When app is background and link is clicked then it should navigate to set password screen but it (throughs an exception which i have mentioned below) takes to that screen which was open when app was moved to background.

D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
D/SurfaceView(25703): Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x5 surface={Surface(name=null)/@0x54b5e07 isValid=false 0}
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/InputTransport(25703): Input channel destroyed: fd=92
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x1 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x1 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
D/SurfaceView(25703): Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x7 surface={Surface(name=null)/@0x54b5e07 isValid=true 543154356736}
D/mali_winsys(25703): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
I/flutter (25703): querParam=e144efdbd666e615a47ebe18e25a556d
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x7 surface={isValid=true 542519654912} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 542519654912} hwInitialized=true
D/mali_winsys(25703): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
D/ViewRootImpl@5c26021MainActivity: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 542519654912}
V/InputMethodManager(25703): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@6fb193a nm : com.root.amployee ic=null
I/InputMethodManager(25703): [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(25703): Input channel constructed: fd=93

E/flutter (25703): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null.
E/flutter (25703): Receiver: null
E/flutter (25703): Tried calling: ancestorStateOfType(Instance of 'TypeMatcher')
E/flutter (25703): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with the library itself. Because the `context` you access is not accessible in the present. So what I suggest is for you to create the global navigator state inside your `MaterialApp` or `CupertinoApp`

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      key: _navigatorKey,
      home: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```